# how to upload file using QFileDialog PySide6

Tags: python, pyside6

am trying to upload an image using PySide6 and i get this error

```
QImage::QImage(), XPM is not supported
```

here is my code

```
def openbtn(self):
    self.ui.pushButton_36.clicked.connect(self.open)

def open(self):
    path = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open file', 
     'c:\\',"Image files (*.jpg *.gif)")
    
    self.ui.label.setPixmap(QPixmap(path))
    self.ui.label.setScaledContents(True)
```

Comment: What is the image format? Because it seems that QFileDialog did its job but it seems that QPixmap doesn't support that format.

Comment: What platform are you on? How did you install PySide? What is the result of this command? `print([str(fmt, 'utf-8') for fmt in QtGui.QImageReader.supportedImageFormats()])`

Comment: yes i installed pyside6  via pip and the image format is in .jpg

Comment: the result of the command is ['bmp', 'cur', 'gif', 'icns', 'ico', 'jpeg', 'jpg', 'pbm', 'pgm', 'png', 'ppm', 'svg', 'svgz', 'tga', 'tif', 'tiff', 'wbmp', 'webp', 'xbm', 'xpm']

Answer (score 1):

this worked

```
fname = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Open file', 
     'c:\\',"Image files (*.jpg *.gif *.svg)")
imagepath = fname[0]
pix = QPixmap(imagepath)
self.ui.label_80.setPixmap(QPixmap(pix))
self.ui.label_80.setScaledContents(True)
```